# On the proof that the successor of an ordinal is also an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

**Definition**.  A set $\alpha$ is an ordinal if it is
transitive and strictly well-ordered by $\in$.

The proofs I have seen (e.g. Lemma 2.5 in [Jech and Hrbacek](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Introduction_to_Set_Theory_Third_Edition/Er1r0n7VoSEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=successor%20ordinal%20number&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover) or p.32 in these [notes](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/SetTheoryHT18.pdf)) go like this:

First they show that $\alpha^+:=\alpha\cup \{\alpha\}$ is transitive.

Second they show that every non-empty subset $S\subset \alpha^+$ contains an $\in$-least element.

I have no problem with these arguments, but it seems to me we are missing a piece, namely the proof that $\in$ is a strict linear order on $\alpha^+$.

I think asymmetry and transitivity both follow from the fact that $\in$ is a strict order on $\alpha$ and that $\alpha \notin \alpha$ for any ordinal $\alpha$, which is proved after as Lemma 2.7 in [Jech and Hrbacek](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Introduction_to_Set_Theory_Third_Edition/Er1r0n7VoSEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=successor%20ordinal%20number&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover). The fact that $\in$ is total on $\alpha^+$ follows from the fact that $\in$ is total on $\alpha$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A strict order in which ever non-empty subset contains a least element is necessarily total (think about the least element of $\{x, y\}$.

Comment: I think you misread the proof in Hrbacek and Jech.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen What am I missing?

Comment: @RobArthan Agree. But we still need to show asymmetry and transitivity right?

Comment: @Alain You characterize the second part of the proof as 'showing that every subset has a $\in$-least element', but I see little relationship between that and what they wrote. Their argument is "if you have a well-ordering and you stick a new element on top, then the result is a well-ordering"... which is maybe a bit sketchy and under-detailed, but intended to be encompassing all the properties of a well-ordering.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ok but the pathology $\alpha \in \alpha$ cannot be ruled out from this argument no?

Comment: @Alain I think that’s right and they should have stated/proved that first (of course it’s an immediate consequence of $\in$ being irreflexive on $\alpha$)

Comment: @Alain on second thought, I guess if we did have $\alpha\in \alpha$, then we’d have $S(\alpha)=\alpha$ and it’d be an ordinal on that account. Nonetheless probably clearer to say it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a set $\alpha$ is an ordinal is suffices to show that

1. $\alpha$ is transitive.
2. Every non-empty subset of $\alpha$ has an $\in$-*minimal* member.
3. Trichotomy: For every $x,y\in\alpha$ either $x\in y$ or $x=y$ or $y\in x$.

Here's how to get the rest

- Irreflexivity: If $x\in\alpha$, the subset $\{x\}$ has an $\in$-minimal member, which must be $x$, so $x\not\in x$.
- Antisymmetry: If $x,y\in\alpha$ and $x\ne y$, the subset $\{x,y\}$ has an $\in$-minimal member, so either $x\not\in y$ or $y\not\in x$.
- Transitivity of $\in$: Let $x,y,z\in\alpha$ with $x\in y$ and $y\in z$.  The subset $\{x,y,z\}$ has an $\in$-minimal member, which must be $x$.  So $z\not\in x$.  Also, $z\ne x$ because otherwise $y\in x=z$ contradicting the $\in$-minimality of $x$.  By the trichotomy, $x\in z$.
- Totality of order - by the trichotomy.
- Every non-empty subset has an $\in$-least member - since $\alpha$ is totally ordered by $\in$, an $\in$-minimal member is an $\in$-least member.

Edit: If $S$ is a set, $R$ a relation and $x\in S$

- $x$ is called $R$-minimal if $\forall z\in S\; \neg zRx$.
- $x$ is called $R$-least if $\forall z\in S\; (x=z\lor xRz)$.

The definition of $R$-least does not prohibit the possibility that $xRx$ or $zRx$ for some $z\in S$.

Edit 2: To complete the proof that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal so is $\alpha^+$:

- $\alpha^+$ is transitive is in the notes.
- Trichotomy: If $x,y\in\alpha^+$, three cases.  Either $x,y\in\alpha$ in which case they're $\in$-comparable since $\alpha$ is an ordinal.  Or exactly one of $x,y$ is in $\alpha$, say $x\in\alpha$ and $y=\alpha$.  Then $x\in y$.  Third case is $x=y=\alpha$.
- Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $\alpha^+$.  First, $\alpha\not\in\alpha$ because otherwise $\{\alpha\}$ would be a non-empty subset of $\alpha$ with no $\in$-minimal member.  Also, if $x\in\alpha$ then $\alpha\not\in x$ because otherwise by transitivity of $\alpha$, $\alpha\in\alpha$.  Now, if $S\cap\alpha\ne\emptyset$, let $y$ be an $\in$-minimal member of $S\cap\alpha$.  Since $\alpha\not\in y$, $y$ is also an $\in$-minimal member of $S$.  Second case, if $S\cap\alpha=\emptyset$ then necessarily $S=\{\alpha\}$ so $\alpha$ is the $\in$-minimal member of $S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its a nice characterization of ordinals. It seems to me the key point is to rule out the pathological case $\alpha \in \alpha$.

Comment: @Alain: $R$-minimal is a more stable concept that makes sense to discuss for any relation.  $R$-least is only useful for a relation already known to be a partial order (strict or non-strict.)